# Cast de Object[i] a String

Tags: java, cast, casting

tengo un pequeño inconveniente con el cast de un arreglo de objetos, la situación es la siguiente:

Tengo un array de objectos ( `Object[]` ) el cual tiene una longitud fija de 21 elementos entre los cuales hay diferentes tipos de datos, (`String, Long, Integer, Double`). Haciendo debug y usar el analizador de variables sobre una posición `i` este me dice que es de tipo `Integer`, al realizar un cast sobre la posición `i` del arreglo con el tipo correspondiente no hay problema

```
Integer dato = (Integer)Object[i]; // No presenta error
```

Sin embargo si requiero castearlo a otro tipo de dato me genera excepción `java.lang.ClassCastException`,

```
String dato (String)Object[i] // genera Excepción
Long dato (Long)Object[i]) // genera excepción
```

Para el caso podria realizar el cast con el tipo interno que el analizador de código muestra (en este caso `Integer`), sin embargo el arreglo de objetos viene de un API y me preocupa que si el valor (para este caso el ubicado en la posición `i`), a futuro sea más grande de forma que se represente como un `Long` y genere una perdida de datos o una excepción de cast dado que se dejo para hacer `cast` como un `Integer`.

Hay alguna forma de solucionar o definir el cast para que no se genere excepciones o perdida de datos?

Comment: Esto puede servirte: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8973685/5525964

Comment: @Lobos gracias, me dio la idea de como hacerlo, tomo los valores como String y lo paso a los contructores del dato que se requiere ej `Long.valueOf(object[i].toString())`